# Chrome Devtools is missing Sources when attached to remote Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm running Chrome 67 on Windows connecting to my Ubuntu PC which is running NodeJS 8
I have an ssh tunnel setup to the Ubuntu PC so I can connect the Chrome Debugger to Node.

`Chrome://inspect/#devices` correctly spots the Remote Target

This allows me to click on the `inspect` link to open the debugger.

The Debugger connects and the console prints debug data from the running Node JS app confirming that things look good.

In the console messages, I can click on the links and have them open the source files

If I click on the `Sources` tab, I expect to see a `Sources` side panel ([ref](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/debugging-node-js-with-google-chrome-4965b5f910f4)) displaying the file hierarchy but it seems to be completely lacking.

[image: screenshot of chrome dev tools]

[image]

If I click on `Add folder to workspace` then it opens up a local file browser.

Has this feature been removed in newer versions of Chrome? If so is there a new way to view the remote file list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not click on `Inspect` under Remote Target

Click on `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`

[image]

This will launch a specific version of DevTools configured for Node which features the Node file system

Comment: still not showing source files. do in need to open source folder in source panel

Comment: @last_fix, in DevTools go to Sources=>Node

Comment: @Vitaly There is nothing under Sources -> Node in my case. I'm running the file with `node --inspect test-server.js`. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @Utku, make sure chrome shows your app under Remote Target as in the screenshot in this answer above (where is says node_modules/mocha/... on the screenshot) and you have inspect link